# I have date format in form 1989-09-26T09:00:00.000+05:30 in a csv file

Tags: hive

On loading data in hive table , I am getting NULL in all date column, when i fetch the rows from Hive table .

Also i want to just fetch the date, not timestamp , so any possible solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you do indicate column with datetime as string in your table definition and parse and cast as date, e.g.,

```
select cast(regexp_extract('1989-09-26T09:00:00.000+05:30', '(\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2})T.*', 1) as date);
```

You can use Hive macro for convenience as well, e.g.,

```
create temporary macro parse_date(ts string)
  cast(regexp_extract(ts, '(\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2})T.*', 1) as date);
```

then

```
select parse_date('1989-09-26T09:00:00.000+05:30');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use to_date function from Hive to extract only the date from the timestamp

**Example:**

```
hive> select to_date('1989-09-26T09:00:00.000+05:30');
+-------------+--+
|     _c0     |
+-------------+--+
| 1989-09-26  |
+-------------+--+
```